# ¿Como puedo leer imagenes local con ElectronJS?

Tags: javascript, electron

Quiero hacer una aplicación para leer imagenes de un directorio en electronjs pero no lo consigo cuando lo publico en producción.
Tengo el siguiente código de ejemplo:

```
 <Image src={ `./static/images/${item.num}.jpg` } rounded />
```

¿Alguien sabe por que no reconoce la ruta del proyecto?

Saludos

Comment: Realicé una sencilla aplicación con tres archivos; `main.js`, `index.html` y `electron.jpg` y no tengo ningún problema para cargar la imagen usando el mismo tag `img` de tu código. Incluso la empaqueté con `electron-packager` y todo sigue funcionando. Podrías dar más detalles de como reproducir el error ?